# Webpack failing to parse jsx

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm confused as to why my webpack configuration is seemingly unable to parse a jsx file.
[On Github](https://github.com/Travmatth/sensible-react-starter/tree/build-crash) 
My Project:

```
.eslintrc

.babelrc

.gitignore

package.json

dist/

spec/

node_modules/

src/

- index.html

- index.jsx

- components/

- - Hello.jsx

- - App.jsx

tools/

- webpack.config.js

- .jscrc
```

My stdout:

```
> sensible-react-starter@1.0.0 build /Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter
> webpack ./src/index.jsx ./dist/index_bundle.js

Hash: deac71a9c994d8034988

Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 41ms
   [0] ./src/index.jsx 0 bytes [built] [failed]

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/src/index.jsx Unexpected token (8:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:2)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1483:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:330:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:225:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:204:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:151:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:133:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:110:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprList (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:657:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:249:29)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:228:15)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:204:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:151:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:133:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:110:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:86:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1753:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1648:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1616:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:882:44)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/Trav/Projects/Templates/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sensible-react-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sensible starter kit for react applications: React, ES6, and much more",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'no test-runner found' && exit(1)",
    "build": "webpack ./src/index.jsx ./dist/index_bundle.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://www.github.com/Travmatth/sensible-react-starter"
  },
  "author": "Travis Matthews",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-alpha6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  }
}
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015", 
        "stage-0",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
/**
 * http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/developing_with_webpack/
 * https://github.com/Travmatth/webpack-express-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js
 */

const path = require('path'); 
const webpack = require('webpack'); 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + '../src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
      }); 

// To execute:
// $ webpack ./src/index.js ./dist/bundle.js
module.exports = {
  // What does this do?
  //devtool: 'eval-source-map'
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, '../src')
  ],

  // Add resolve.extensions
  // '' is needed to allow imports without an extension
  // Note the .'s before extensions as it will fail to match without
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js', 
    publicPath: './dist/'
  },

  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { // Configure css
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
        // include: path.join(__dirname, '../src/')
      },
      { // Configure jsx - accepts .js as well thx to RegExp
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // Parse only app files!
        // Without this, would go through entire app
        include: path.join(__dirname, '../src/'),
        // exclude: /node_modules/
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        // Enable caching for improved performance during dev
        // Uses default directory by default
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-0', 'es2015']
        },
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> sensible-react-starter </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <meta name="description" description="description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
</html>
<body>
  <h1>Is this working?</h1>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="./index_bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

My index.jsx:

```
import './main.css'; 
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import App from './components/App.jsx'; 

console.log('index.jsx entered'); 
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

My Hello.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'; 

console.log('Hello.jsx entered')
export default () => <p>Learn Webpack</p>;
```

In all my googling / stack-overflowing, the only related build failures i can find are due to react not being included / implemented correctly - if this is the case with my code i cannot see where.

Comment: Can you paste your directory structure? A `tree` would work.

Comment: @bebraw added a skeleton and linked the github, if that'd help any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are not running your webpack config.

I tried checking out build-crash branch, but it doesn't have all the above changes.

I've since copied package.json overtop of the branch code, and webpack.config.js and get:

```
TypeError: HtmlWebpackPluginConfig is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/halkeye/git/sensible-react-starter/tools/webpack.config.js:37:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at module.exports (/home/halkeye/git/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/halkeye/git/sensible-react-starter/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:39:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
```

So I fixed up things. Firstly, running webpack without a config, will just look for webpack.config.js in your current directory (which I recommend). Failing that you can provide a new path with --config parameter.

https://gist.github.com/00b5862100b5886206d910a56157d595

```
 $ webpack --config tools/webpack.config.js
Hash: e14e332ded87ce062f10
Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 2512ms
          Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index_bundle.js     686 kB       0  [emitted]  main
     index.html  474 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 166 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 3 hidden modules
```

The key things for me was running with --config, and fixing the typo in your webpack about HtmlWebpackPluginConfig.

Also couldn't get your path.joins to work right, kept erroring file not found (maybe because i'm linux), so I switched to path.resolve